# Phonegap: How can I disable the default touch sound?

Tags: html, cordova, dom-events, phonegap-build

Well this was very annoying because when I tested it worked. But I have compiled the Application and every time I touch the buttons there is the default sound from Android, like a "bloop".

Does anyone know how to disable this?

UPDATE:

I have develop that plugin. It can be installed and the app runs but it is not working. This are the features of the plugin:

plugin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 
<plugin xmlns="http://www.phonegap.com/ns/plugins/1.0"
           id="org.trollglodita.sounds"
      version="0.1.0">
    <name>sound</name>
    <description>Sample PhoneGap Sound Plugin</description>
    <license>RO</license>
    <keywords>phonegap,sound</keywords>
 
    <!-- android -->
    <platform name="android">
        <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
            <feature name="sound">
                <param name="android-package" value="org.trollglodita.sound"/>
            </feature>
        </config-file>

        <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
        </config-file>
         
        <source-file src="src/android/sound.java"/>      
     </platform>          
</plugin>
```

plugin/src/android/preventsound.java

```
package org.apache.cordova.plugin;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

    /**
     * This class echoes a string called from JavaScript.
     */


public class SoundBeep extends CordovaPlugin {
    AudioManager aManager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    aManager.setRingerMode(aManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
}

@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possibe write simple plugin for that

inside that plugin add this java code thats all,

```
AudioManager aManager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
aManager.setRingerMode(aManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

**For android plugin development check [this](http://devgirl.org/2013/09/17/how-to-write-a-phonegap-3-0-plugin-for-android/)**

Comment: Arjun, I've followed the tutorial but the plugin is not working even if it installed properly and the app runs, the plugin is not getting the feature to work. I've also tried with `navigator.notification.vibrate(0)` but it doesn't work neither.